# AsyncSocket and CFSocket, how to set TCP's Urgent Flag?

Tags: iphone, networking, tcp

I'm using **AsyncSocket** to write a TCP client on iPhone and need to set the **Urgent Flag** of TCP segments.

How to do it? I can't find relative APIs in CFSocket.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call CFSocketGetNative() and do whatever you need on the native socket.